# asp.net mvc3, api twitter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-twitter

Somebody can explain me this code :

```
auth = new MvcAuthorizer
       {
           Credentials = credentials               
       };

       auth.CompleteAuthorization(Request.Url);



var auth = new MvcAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = new SessionStateCredentials()
            {
                ConsumerKey = this.client.ConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = this.client.ConsumerSecret,
                OAuthToken = identity.Token.Token
            }
        };
```

the difference between the two codes

Thanks,

Comment: You're going to confuse a lot of people with this :)  This site is more for asking for help with specific problems.  The question you asked is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, there is no difference. I'm making the assumption that "credentials" in the first example is a SessionStateCredentials that was instantiated previously in the code.  The second example uses object initialization syntax to do the same thing.